# Where can I find beginners electronics project schematics online, for free?

Tags: basic

I have bought the following books in order to start learning basic electronics:

- [Electronics All-In-One Desk Reference For Dummies](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470147040)
- [Robot Building for Beginners (Technology in Action)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430227486)

My desire though, is for a good book that has a lot of projects in it that starts from the basic level, such as; from a few LEDs and a battery, to more advanced circuits such as making dot matrix displays for around the house and even up to robotics.

I really am serious about this and have even purchased a learn to solder kit which i aced well.

I have searched online, but since I am inexperienced, I don't know what is good.

Comment: I found this little book at my dump for free. It's old, but it's really pretty good http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0007K6908  ($4 used)

Comment: @kenny, yes this book is great for beginners.

Comment: Unfortunately this book appears to be heavily outdated and old, besides i already have a book on electronics. I am just looking for plans i can build or a book with many plans in it with complete instructions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [From zero to "almost pro": Newbie trying to learn. Good, quick resources?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4658/from-zero-to-almost-pro-newbie-trying-to-learn-good-quick-resources)

Comment: This is just one, but there are many more: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8082/what-are-some-simple-and-informative-beginners-projects

Comment: Survey questions like this are not a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 7):

Some fun websites with tons of projects...

- http://hackedgadgets.com
- http://hackaday.com
- http://www.allaboutcircuits.com
- http://www.pyroelectro.com

Best of luck!

One more good and fun resource is a magazine called Nutz and Volts. Usually available at your local bookstore in the US. I started out with a subscription when I was first starting out with electronics -- *MANY* moons ago. Way back then it was called "poptronics"
http://www.nutsvolts.com

Answer (score 1):

From the world of analog electronics (audio!): https://sound-au.com/index2.html

Check out the project list and the articles.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another site with electronics design tutorial including schematics design and PCB design

http://appliedelectronicsengineering.blogspot.de

i hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I have also seen some websites like

http://www.edgefxkits.com

http://www.elprocus.com

which are having some good projects ideas from basic level to middle level. Once you may check it.